# Science fiction story about head of secret school finding a construct that answers questions

Tags: story-identification

Commander of a secret military school finds a construct that answers questions. The commander asks how build a machine for instantly transporting objects. Then tries it himself and finds that the external time is 0 seconds, but the internal time is longer than his air supply. The construct tells him the only way to survive is to become a construct himself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good story-identification question.  If they help you recall any more details, you can [edit] them into your question.

Comment: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. If not, you may consider editing your question to add more details about the story (how old, novel or short, any character or place names you can recall, etc.)

Comment: Was Damon Knight's "Ask Me Anything" the story you were looking for?

Answer (score 15):

["Ask Me Anything"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55241), a novelette by [Damon Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Knight), first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, May 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58587+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v02n02_1951-05#page/n133). Does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?55241) ring a bell?

> Krisch mastered himself sufficiently to say evenly, "I was not able to enter normal space at my destination. Why not?"
>
> "You did not wait long enough. There is a great disparity between the time rates of this plenum and the normal one; that is why travel can be achieved at a rate which cannot be distinguished from simultaneity by your methods. In subjective terms, the trip to Cynara will take you a long time."
>
> "How long?" Krisch demanded. He felt helpless, fixed like a pinned specimen in the midst of this gray infinity.
>
> "Approximately one thousand of your years."
>
> Krisch felt his face writhe and distort into the silent shape of a stream. Blood pounded at his temples; his eyes filmed. He said, "How long back to the cavern?"
>
> "Only one year, if you were to start immediately to concentrate on the objective. If you allow yourself to drift, as you are doing now, the distance will widen rapidly."
>
> "But I've only got enough air for twenty hours!" Krisch shouted. "I'll die!"
>
> [. . . .]
>
> *"Is there any way for me to escape from it?"*
>
> The Pattern said, "Yes. It is the final jest of my makers. To travel in hyperspace, you must become what I am—only a pattern of forces and memory, not alive, not intelligent, not capable of boredom. I can make this alteration, if you request it. It is simple, like the growth of one crystal from another, or like the transfer of pattern in living cells."